# SWI-PL: read() after a writeln() / write(),nl holds out the output of all previous write()

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to make a prolog menu in which the script asks the user to enter some data, so it's all a chain of write(), read(), nl and maybe some writeln().

The problem is that for some reason the read() function holds out the output of the write until all the reads finish. That is a problem becasue all those writes are telling the suer what to enter.

I made a test code for showing what happens, because my actual project is a mess:

```
test:-
    write("X is "),
    read(X),
    writeln("Y is "),
    read(Y),
    writeln("Z is "),
    read(Z),
    write([X,Y,Z]).
```

This what I expect:

```
?- test.
X is
|: 1.
Y is
|: 2.
Z is
|: 3.
[1,2,3]
true.
```

But this is what I get:

```
?- test.
1.
|: 2.
|: 3.
X is Y is Z is [1,2,3]
true.
```

SWI is threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.4, and I'm in KDE Neon 5.16.2 (Based on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-54

Comment: tried both write(),nl and writeln(). both have the same issue.

Thing is that all the writes work until the last one before the read(), and after the last read() executes, all the dragged carried write() execute.

Comment: BTW, you are using a very old version of Prolog. If you are on Ubuntu, follow [these instructions](https://www.swi-prolog.org/build/PPA.txt) to get an up-to date SWI-Prolog.

Comment: No, I'm in Fedora Workstation 30

Comment: On Linux, it is quite straight-forward to install from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `flush_output/0` after the `write/1`, like this:

```
test:-
    write("X is "), flush_output,
    read(X),
    writeln("Y is "), flush_output,
    read(Y),
    writeln("Z is "), flush output,
    read(Z),
    write([X,Y,Z]).
```

But I actually cannot reproduce your problem. With exactly your code, without any flushing, I see on my terminal:

```
?- test.
X is 1.
Y is 
|: 2.
Z is 
|: 3.
[1,2,3]
true.
```

So, we see different things. Why?

- We have different versions of SWI-Prolog on different OSs?
- You don't type exactly the same things as I type?

Difficult to say. But make sure to read [the documentation of `flush_output/0`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flush_output/0), there might be a clue there of what is going on.